# How do you get large SAV Files (1k columns) into Postgres preferably using Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, pentaho, spss

I have 5 large SAV files, consisting of over a thousand columns, which I want to put into a PostgreS db. How do I get the SAV files into Postgres best without losing the data values or value labels and other meta information that is stored in the 'variable' view in SPSS.

Have been looking into Python packages like pyreadstat since I'm not R savvy.

Comment: What is the expectation how the values are stored? Should it be just quick and dirty and cast everything to text. HUGE JSONB blobs are fine with the metadata - or - should it be an SPSS like experience...

Comment: And - please share an example sav file.

Comment: I would say more like a SPSS kinda experience..